# Webpack - The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, webpack

I am trying to implement Webpack in Visual Studio for Angular app.

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const source = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts');
const destination = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = {
    entry: source,
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: destination
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|html)$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
    ]
};
```

**Index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

[image: Solution Explorer structure]

I am able to build bundle file by running webpack command, but when I run Visual Studio and direct to index.html, it throws error:

**The selector "my-app" did not match any elements**

I am not sure what I am missing,  I have looked over all internet SO, Git, Webpack docs etc but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Have you looked at instead starting with the Angular CLI as your build tool?

Comment: That would be easier I understand but I am trying to implement it from scratch in order to get complete understanding.

Comment: You can always detach their webpack configuration and see what they have set up vs what you do.

Comment: If you create a sample project using the CLI, you can run the `ng eject` command and it will give you the entire `webpack.config.js` file they were using.

Comment: I don't think its issue with webpack.config, since bundle is created. and anyway I am using official documentation to create config file. I have posted my config file above, if you can point out if I am missing something that would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why your html template is loading your `index.js` file three times? I think your error above is from the first inclusion of the script in the head of the document.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="index.js"></script> <!-- this guy here -->
</head>
...
</html>
```

I tested moving my scripts for Angular to the head and received the same type of error.

Comment: This is how it was generated by webpack.

Comment: Look in your `'./src/index.html'` file and I bet you have the `<script>` tags being included in there. My guess is that WebPack is putting the last one in there: `<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>`

Comment: You are right. I had included script in src/index, which made bundle file repeating same script causing the error. thanks a lot. :)